# How to stop Looping - Javascript 100%

Tags: javascript, loops

I was hoping someone could help me figure this out. I will list the code, and it works just fine, as it is an animation. However, when I check it out in the console it wont stop looping even though it hit the last item in the array. The image itself stops, but if you view the console it shows it looping.

Here is the code, have at it!

```js
 var position_X = ["0px", "-525px", "-1050px", "-1575px", "-2100px", "-2625px", "-3150px", "-3675px", "-4200px", "-4725px", "-5250px", "-5775px", "-6300px", "-6825px", "-7350px"];

 var _lock = document.getElementById('hi');

  // console.log(_lock);
  _lock.style.border = "1px solid black";
  _lock.style.backgroundImage = "url('http://handbagmanufacturing.com/wp-content/CDN/images/lock.png')";

 function lockAnimation(){
   setInterval(function(){
    var _count = position_X.length;
    for(var i = 0; i < _count; i++){
     if(i == _count) break;
      _lock.style.backgroundPosition = position_X[i] + " 263px";
      console.log("Here is the background positions : " + i + ") " + position_X[i]);
     }
    }
   , 100); 
 }
```

```css
#hi {
      width: 525px;
      height: 263px;
      background-position-x: "-7875px"
  }
```

```html
<button onclick="lockAnimation()">Click Me I'm Irish!</button>
 <div id="hi"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Change `setInterval` to `setTimeout`. This will run the function only once instead of running it every 100 ms.

```js
 var position_X = ["0px", "-525px", "-1050px", "-1575px", "-2100px", "-2625px", "-3150px", "-3675px", "-4200px", "-4725px", "-5250px", "-5775px", "-6300px", "-6825px", "-7350px"];

 var _lock = document.getElementById('hi');

  // console.log(_lock);
  _lock.style.border = "1px solid black";
  _lock.style.backgroundImage = "url('http://handbagmanufacturing.com/wp-content/CDN/images/lock.png')";

 function lockAnimation(){
   setTimeout(function(){
    var _count = position_X.length;
    for(var i = 0; i < _count; i++){
     if(i == _count) break;
      _lock.style.backgroundPosition = position_X[i] + " 263px";
      console.log("Here is the background positions : " + i + ") " + position_X[i]);
     }
    }
   , 100); 
 }
```

```css
#hi {
      width: 525px;
      height: 263px;
      background-position-x: "-7875px"
  }
```

```html
<button onclick="lockAnimation()">Click Me I'm Irish!</button>
 <div id="hi"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you!! Would you happen to know if I would have to use setInterval within the for loop to control the speed of the for loop? I want to be able to see how much I can slow down each frame. :)

Comment: you can use setInterval instead of the loop and then stop it with clearInterval